# Image changing every day of the year (365 days)

Tags: javascript

I need a little help with my code there are 366 images to change called 001.jpg, 002.jpg ... 366.jpg. It gets the date and put the picture for it. The code works but I can't get it to output in my img tag.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var firstJan = Math.floor((new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear(),0,1))/86400000);
var today = Math.ceil((new Date().getTime())/86400000);
var dayOfYear = today-firstJan;

var bgdImage;
if((dayOfYear+'').length == 1)
bgdImage = '00'+dayOfYear+'.jpg';
else if((dayOfYear+'').length == 2)
bgdImage = '0'+dayOfYear+'.jpg';
else
bgdImage = dayOfYear+'.jpg';

document.getElementById('bla').src = "bgdImage";
</script>

</head>
<body onload=img()>

<img id="bla" width="100%" height="100%" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: wrap the code in the function img() you use in the onload tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I said in the initial comment, put the code in the function `ìmg()` you call in the `<body onload="javascript:img();">`. I also removed the quotes from your output statement to the src. `document.getElementById('bla').src = bgdImage;` `bgdImage` is your variable and putting it in quotes `"bgdImage"` is just a String with the text bgdImage inside.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function img()
{
var firstJan = Math.floor((new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear(),0,1))/86400000);
var today = Math.ceil((new Date().getTime())/86400000);
var dayOfYear = today-firstJan;

var bgdImage;
if((dayOfYear+'').length == 1)
bgdImage = '00'+dayOfYear+'.jpg';
else if((dayOfYear+'').length == 2)
bgdImage = '0'+dayOfYear+'.jpg';
else
bgdImage = dayOfYear+'.jpg';

document.getElementById('bla').src = bgdImage;
}
</script>

</head>
<body onload="javascript:img();">

<img id="bla" width="100%" height="100%" />

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Take the double-quotes off:

```
document.getElementById('bla').src = bgdImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem in your code looks like you are setting the src of the image to the String "bgdImage" rather than the variable.  Try replacing the line with this:

```
document.getElementById('bla').src = bgdImage;
```

**UPDATE**

It also looks like you are trying to run the code before the `img` tag is set up.  Try moving the script to after the `img` tag, or setting a timeout to execute it after the page has completely rendered.

Comment: @Johnny Sooter  Have you inspected the DOM to see if the src on the img is set properly?  Also, are you getting any JavaScript errors?

Comment: @Jonny Scooter don't put your Javascript inline into your HTML's body. Using the function ìmg()` you had already set up in the questions Example is much better. You can also outsource that function to an external .js file later to separate html and js.

Comment: thats what I had in mind all along @C.O. that why I picked your answer